# Landscape orientation for Collection View in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am encountering a problem on landscape orientation for my collection view cell. When the app is in portrait it gives me the correct number of cell per row which is 2. But when I rotate my app to landscape it display 1 cell per row. Here's the screen of what I got:

**Portrait:**
[image]

**Landscape:**
[image]

Here's my code for adding the size of the cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var screenSize = CGFloat()
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
            screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        }
        else {
            screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        }

        let cellWidth = screenSize / 2.0

        return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
if(orientation == .LandscapeLeft || orientation == .LandscapeRight)
{
    return CGSizeMake((yourCollectionView.frame.size.width-10)/2, (yourCollectionView.frame.size.height-10)/2)
}
else{
    return CGSizeMake((yourCollectionView.frame.size.width-5)/2, (yourCollectionView.frame.size.height-10)/3)
}
```

What this code achieves:- If your view is in portrait you will see 2 column and 3 row and if your view is in landscape you will see 3 columns and 2 row. The deduction you see in the code is the spacing between two consecutive cells. So if there is 3 column the deduction is 15 and if there is 2 column the deduction is 10 assuming that the spacing between two cell is 5. Same goes for the row.

You can use the screen size as well if you want but I had auto layout constraints in my collection view to match the size of the screen so it resulted the same. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi, This is the closest on what I am looking for but I want it to be the same with portrait and landscape with 2 columns.

Comment: That can easily be achieved. I will update my answer for you. But I do not think it will look good.

Answer (score 1):

Just reload your `UICollectionView` in

override

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        yourCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

and your collection view layout will refresh again when orientation changed

Update:
This is code snippet for `collectionView` layout making 4 image view in each row from my code, and its working even it changing orientation from portrait to landscape and vice versa. You can change it to your need:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4.8, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4.8)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 0.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 16.0
}
```

Hope it will helps you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var flag:CGSize? = nil
    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad
    {
        if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait{

            let cellWidth = floor((collectionView.bounds.width - 5) / 2)
            flag = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
        }

        else if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape{

            let cellwidth = floor((collectionView.bounds.width - 5) / 4)
            flag =  CGSize(width: cellwidth, height: cellwidth)

        }

    }
    else if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone{

        if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
          let cellWidth = floor((collectionView.bounds.width - 5) / 2)
            flag = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
        } else if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait{
            //  let cellWidth = floor((collectionView.bounds.width - 5))
            flag = CGSize(width: 402 , height: 185)
        }

    }

    return flag!
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your question accordingly since pure-code answers are very likely to be flagged for closure.

Answer (score 1):

don't reload your collection view just invalidate your collection view flowlayour Done

if you don't understand what is that means just copy and paste this code and change your collection view name

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

fiveCellCustomCollectionView is my custom view and customCollectionView is collection view

```
  guard let flowLayout = fiveCellCustomCollectionView.customCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }
  flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
    if(orientation == .landscapeLeft || orientation == .landscapeRight) {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width-10)/2, height: (collectionView.frame.size.height-10)/2)
    }
    else {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width-5)/2, height: (collectionView.frame.size.height-10)/3)
    }
```