# How to achieve Grid view using collection view cell swift ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

Please let me know How to make grid view like 2 cell per each column for portrait and 3 cell for landscape. Using collection view custom cell without using pods or third party framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
       return CGSizeMake(collectionViewSize/3, collectionViewSize/3)
    }
    else if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
            return CGSizeMake(collectionViewSize/2, collectionViewSize/2)
    }
    return CGSizeZero
}
```

you also need to reload on orientation change

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

func rotated()
{
   collectionView.reloadData() 
}
```

**Note**: Make sure you will confirm `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol

Answer (score 1):

I have answered similar question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152071/landscape-orientation-for-collection-view-in-swift/37152739#37152739). I have even explained how to change the view to match your requirement. In your case it might look something like this.

```
let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
if(orientation == .LandscapeLeft || orientation == .LandscapeRight)
{
    return CGSizeMake((yourCollectionView.frame.size.width-10)/3, (yourCollectionView.frame.size.height-10)/3)
}
else{
   return CGSizeMake((yourCollectionView.frame.size.width-5)/2, (yourCollectionView.frame.size.height-5)/2)
}
```

The deduction is the cell padding(which is 5 in my case). If 3 cells, then 2 cell padding making total of 10 deduction and if 2 cells, then 1 cell padding making total of 5 deduction. Hope this helps.