# UICollectionView cell spacing for both portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

My goal is to make equal spacing between the cells for the portrait and landscape orientation. I am able to do it for the portrait orientation but not for the landscape orientation. I wanted to close the gap in the landscape orientation by stretching the image width and height.

I want 2 cells per row for portrait view and 3 cells per row for landscape view.

[image: Portrait Orientation]
[image: Landscape Orientation]

My code is the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2
        let padding: CGFloat = 5
        let totalPadding = padding * (itemsPerRow - 1)
        let individualPadding = totalPadding / itemsPerRow
        let width = (collectionView?.frame.width)! / itemsPerRow - individualPadding
        let height = width
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = padding
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = padding
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152071/landscape-orientation-for-collection-view-in-swift?rq=1 refer this may help you

Comment: Create a custom UICollectionviewFlowlayout and update item size while landscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    return cell
}


var spacing: CGFloat = 8

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spacing
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spacing
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let safeFrame = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
    let size = CGSize(width: safeFrame.width, height: safeFrame.height)
    return setCollectionViewItemSize(size: size)

}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}

func setCollectionViewItemSize(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait {
        let width = (size.width - 1 * spacing) / 2
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    } else {
        let width = (size.width - 2 * spacing) / 3
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
}
```

The outcome is like this:

[image]

Comment: A reminder to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Confirm `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

e.g.

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screeSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let numOfCell:Int = 2 //Number of items you want
        let spaceOfCell:CGFloat = (CGFloat((numOfCell + 1)*10)) //Space between Cells

let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
    if(orientation == .LandscapeLeft || orientation == .LandscapeRight)
    {
       return CGSize(width: Int(screeSize.width - (spaceOfCell/2)) / (numOfCell + 1), height: Int(screeSize.width - spaceOfCell) / numOfCell+1)  

    }
    else
    {
       return CGSize(width: Int(screeSize.width - (spaceOfCell)) / numOfCell, height: Int(screeSize.width - spaceOfCell) / numOfCell)

    }

}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.00
        //Verticle space between line
    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.00 //Space Between Items You want
    }
```

Comment: I still have a big vertical space in the middle.

Comment: I wanted to have 3 cells in a row for landscape orientation.

Comment: I've edited my old answer  now try this new instead old

Answer (score 0):

Without further ado...

```
private var numberOfCellsPerRow: Int {
    return (UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .portrait) ? 2 : 3
}

private let spacing: CGFloat = 20

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 24
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = .orange
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return .zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spacing
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spacing
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let availableWidth = collectionView.frame.width - CGFloat(numberOfCellsPerRow - 1) * spacing
    let cellWidth = availableWidth / CGFloat(numberOfCellsPerRow)
    return .init(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```